# Deleting a many-to-many relation without a PK

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have the following model in a DRF API:

```
class InstrumentosMusico(models.Model):
    musico = models.ForeignKey(Musico, related_name="instrumentos")
    instrumento = models.ForeignKey(Instrumento)
    novo = models.BooleanField(null=False)
    remover = models.BooleanField(null=False)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "musicos_instrumentos"
        unique_together = ("musico", "instrumento")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%d" % (self.instrumento)
```

How can send a DELETE request so I can delete such an object?

Comment: This information is readily available in the documentation for the django-rest-framework. Take a look at generic views [link](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views#generic-views) and read the tutorial there if you're having trouble

Comment: Thanks! I've found it. My bad.